# php email generation file error

Tags: php, html

I wrote a little order form application about a year ago which would allow a user to select a few items then click submit button the submit button then fires a php script which creates an email invoice for both the person who orders it and the company who is suppy the product.

Now I am still very new to PHP and now that I have come back to it I have forgotten alot of what I wrote and for some reason I am getting an error in my email which I am hoping someone can help me find.

This is what my order form page looks like

[image]

This is the code for that page

```
<p><i>Required fields are marked with</i> <b>*</b></p>

<form action="orderformDNP.php" method="post"
onsubmit="document.getElementById('myButton').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('myButton').value='Submitting...';"
>

<table width="496" border="0" style="border-width: 1px; border-color:#E5E5E5;
border-style: solid;">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Name: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="yourname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Phone Number: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Mobile Number: 
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            E-mail: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">
            Deliver Address: *
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <textarea name="deliveryaddress" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </br>


<!-- this is the ordering part of the form --!>

 <h3>Duvets</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 5050goosedown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>50/50 Goose Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><select name=". $row['goosedown_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br></br>
<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 5050duckdown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>50/50 Duck Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><select name=". $row['duckdown_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br></br>
<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 955goosedown ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'><b>95/5 Goose Down:</b></th>
<th width='30%'><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><select name=". $row['955goosedown_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br>
<h3>Pillows</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goosedownpillows ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='62.5%'><b>Goose Down Pillows:</b></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><select name=". $row['goosedownpillows_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</br>
<h3>Feather Mattress Toppers</h3>

<?php

//Start session
    //session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feathermattresstoppers ORDER BY price ASC");

echo "<table border='0' width='496'>
<tr>
<th width='62.5%'><b>95/5 Mattress Toppers:</b></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Old Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
<th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  }
  if ($row['old_price'] !=0){
    echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><select name=". $row['feathermattresstoppers_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>





<p><b>Additional Info:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>
</br></br>496

Access code: <input type="text" name="code" /><br />
Please enter <i>MYCODE</i> above. </br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myButton" />

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

</td>
```

this is orderformDNP which dose not seem to be working correctly.. which I just cannot tell why..

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $body_items = '';
    $total_price = 0;


    /* Set Redgraves Email address, so they receive the orders  */
    $myemail  = "clientsEmail@gmail.com";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
    $phonenumber = check_input($_POST['phonenumber'], "Enter your phone number");
    $mobilenumber = check_input($_POST['mobilenumber']);
    $email    = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your E-mail address");
    $deliveryaddress = check_input($_POST['deliveryaddress'], "Enter your delivery address");

    $comments = check_input($_POST['comments']);

    $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

    $goosedown_id = ($_POST[$row['goosedown_id']]); 




    if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'mycode') 
    {
        die('Wrong access code');
    }

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    /* If phone number has characters show error message */
    if (preg_match("/\D/",$phonenumber))
    {
        die("Please enter numbers only for Phone Number");
    }

    /* If mobile number has characters show error message */
    if (preg_match("/\D/",$mobilenumber))
    {
        die("Please enter numbers only for Mobile Number");
    }


    // 5050duckdown
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['5050goosedown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>50/50 Goose Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////////////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['5050duckdown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['5050duckdown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>50/50 Duck Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    /////////////////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['955goosedown'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['955goosedown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>95/5 Goose Down:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['goosedownpillows'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['goosedownpillows'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>Goose Down Pillows:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }

    //////
    $flag = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $order_content = '';
    foreach ($_POST['feathermattresstoppers'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $flag = 1;
            if($i%2 == 0)
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
            else
                $order_content .= "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
            $i++;

            if (($row['width'] ==0) && ($row['height']== 0))
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['name'] . "</td>";
            else
                $order_content .=  "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['name'] . "   -" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['width'] . "/" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['height'] .  "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['price'] . "</td>";

            $order_content .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

            $sub = $_SESSION['feathermattresstoppers'][$key]['price'] * $value;
            $total_price += $sub;
            $order_content .= "<td>" . $sub . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    if ($flag = 1) {
        $body_items .= "<table border='0' width='600'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='30%'><b>95/5 Mattress Toppers:</b></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Item Price</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Quantity</i></th>
                                <th width='12.5%'><i>Price</i></th>
                            </tr>";
        $body_items .= $order_content;
        $body_items .= '</table><br /><br />';
    }
    $body_items .= "<br /><b>Total: $total_price</b></b></b>";



/*-------------------First Email--------------------*/

    /* Set Email for Redgraves, so they can for-full the order form */
    $message = "A order form has been submitted by: $yourname<br /><br />

    Order number :<u>$random</u><br /><br />

    <b>Name:</b> $yourname<br />
    <b>E-mail:</b> $email<br />
    <b>Phone Number:</b> $phonenumber<br />
    <b>Mobile Number:</b> $mobilenumber<br />
    <b>Delivery Address:</b> $deliveryaddress<br />
    <b>Comments:</b> $comments<br /><br />

    $body_items


    <br /><br />**End of message**
    ";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
    $header= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header.= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($myemail, "Order Submitted", $message, $header);

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    //mail($myemail, "Order Submitted", $message);

/*---------------Second Email---------------------*/    

    /* This email is to confirm the order and act as a receipt to the purchaser */
    $respond_message = "Order Completed<br /><br />

    Your order has been submitted! details are as follows<br /><br />

    <b>Name:</b> $yourname<br />
    <b>E-mail:</b> $email<br />
    <b>Phone Number:</b> $phonenumber<br />
    <b>Mobile Number:</b> $mobilenumber<br />
    <b>Delivery Address:</b> $deliveryaddress<br />
    <b>Comments:</b> $comments<br /><br />

    $body_items


    <br /><b>Reference Number:</b> <u>$random</u><br /><br />

    Please make payment using the refrence number above within 7 working days or your order will be canceled <br />
    ASB 000-0000-0000-00 ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($email, "Thank you for your order", $respond_message, $headers);


    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();




/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}




function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

this is what is happening to the email... :(

```
A order form has been submitted by: kc

Order number :8674170468

Name: kc
E-mail: testing@gmail.com
Phone Number: 0941
Mobile Number: 64215
Delivery Address: japan
Comments: 

95/5 Mattress Toppers:  Item Price  Quantity    Price



Total: 0 

**End of message**
```

I have been on this for a couple of days now and am woundering maybe can this error be caused by php versions on the Data base or something???

any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE: this is what is generated from **print_r($_POST);**

```
Array ( [yourname] => kc 
        [phonenumber] => 987 
        [mobilenumber] => 987 
        [email] => test@gmail.com 
        [deliveryaddress] => testing 66 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [comments] => sdsdf 
        [code] => MYCODE )
```

Update 2: email output not ouputting price as well as a couple of the other values

[image]

Comment: `Total: 0 `  Is that the error part?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ yes, no matter how many items I select in the first part its alwas returning 0 as my total now.. and always 95/5 Mattress Toppers even if there are no selected values in that area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ($flag = 1)`

should probably be `if ($flag == 1)`

It's written correctly as the latter for most of the conditionals but not the mattress toppers one.  This is why the empty mattress toppers section always appears.

Based on what's showing up in `$_POST` it looks like there is a mismatch between the names of your actual form fields and the names your PHP is expecting to find.  For instance the 50/50 Goosedown section is looking for:  `$_POST['5050goosedown']` but the dropdown I assume is associated with this is `<select name=". $row['goosedown_id'] .">` so it would show up in $_POST with a key equal to whatever `$row['goosedown_id']` is.  It looks like these are numbers (the empty-valued entries in `$_POST` for `1` and `2`.

Why are they empty?  My guess would be these IDs are shared across more than one field so you have multiple selects with the same name and they're conflicting with eachother when submitted.

Try changing the selects to look like this (example for the first one):

```
echo '<td><select name="5050goosedown[' . $row['goosedown_id'] . ']">'
. "<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
and so on
```

This will cause it to show up in `$_POST` as a nested array e.g.

```
array(
    [5050goosedown] => array( 
        [1] => 2, 
        [2] => 
    )
)
```

with the specific item IDs here being 1 and 2.  This seems to be what the PHP code is expecting.

Comment: okay so I changed that and it has taken this line out "95/5 Mattress Toppers:  Item Price  Quantity    Price" but the total is still equal to 0... :(

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` and edit your question to show what that prints out.

Comment: where do I put that statment sorry?

Comment: You can put it at the top of the PHP after `session_start`.  It's just going to display everything that was submitted in the form.

Comment: Be sure not to paste in anything secure being posted like passwords. =)

Comment: okay thank you for your updated question.. I will try it now give me abit of time and I will get back to you with how I have gone

Comment: okay that seems to be working now.. I am just missing a couple of items in the layout. I will update my question with an image to show you I am going to try and find a solution now :).. actually I also just noticed the price is not coming through on it either....

Comment: so I am still at the same point thanks for yourself I have marked your answer correct but if you have any ideas about the issue with price etc that would be really helpfull to hear from you.

Comment: Your PHP is trying to pull those missing values from $_SESSION but I don't see where they have ever been put in $_SESSION.  That is probably why they are missing.  I expect you would need to get them from your database.