# how to name $row to be used later

Tags: php, html

I have a piece of code in a file the gets values from another php file, it looks like this.

```
$sub = $_SESSION['5050goosedown'][$key]['price'] * $value;
```

I would like to relate it to this field in my other php file but I dont know how to format it so its related to the **5050goosedown** identifier, this is what the code looks like

```
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
```

I tried this but it did not work, but it should give you an idea of what I am trying to attempt.

```
echo '<td><name="5050goosedown[' . $row['price'] . ']">' ."
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's not working about it? What is the output you're trying to get and what are you getting?

Comment: can you var_dump or print_r of 5050goosedown and paste it here?

Comment: its related to this question here. essentially my values are not being passed over because they are not matrching any keywords if thats the correct terminology... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631146/php-email-generation-file-error

Comment: @ganeshrj I am not quite sure how to do that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try
`echo "<td"."name=".$5050goosedown[$row['price']].">"."</td>"`

Comment: try print_r($5050goosedown)

Comment: gah... I am not sure how to do this.. I am putting it at the top of my php file that calls the values.

Comment: it just runs as normal. I get no output at all.